# Are there any programs in the US to increase male participation in female-dominated jobs?

Tags: united-states, discrimination, gender

As an example, only 20% of [elementary & middle school teachers](http://menteach.org/resources/data_about_men_teachers) in the US are male, similar to the percentage of software engineers who are female. Are there any government programs in place to address the underrepresentation of men in teaching and other professions such as nursing? Programs which only address the number of men studying in under-represented fields would also count, similar to the efforts by the Obama administration to increase the number of women [taking up STEM subjects](https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/administration/eop/ostp/women).

Given that Western society currently accepts the axiom "men and women are exactly equal", we must presume that there's men out there who want to become teachers but cannot do so due to societal pressure, educational factors or outright discrimination. Therefore the government could be expected to work to address these issues.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments for sociopolitical debates. Comments should be used to suggest improvements to the question.

Comment: Sorry, can't speak for the US, but in Germany this does exist. For example, there is the initiative (and website) ["Klischeefrei"](https://www.klischee-frei.de/) (German for "stereotype-free"), whose stated goal is to support "job choice that is free from gender stereotypes". It explicitly addresses all genders, and has material both on supporting girls in male-dominated fields, such as STEM, and on supporting boys in female-dominated fields (e.g. the program "Boys in Care" to support the choice of social and nursing jobs). It is run by a German government institute.

Comment: Are there government programs to address the underrepresentation in software engineering? I'm aware of activism, but not any government programs, and I live in Seattle.

Comment: @AzorAhai yes, for example: https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/administration/eop/ostp/women

Comment: Are you talking about encouraging *study* (which is what that link seems to be about) or *hiring*?

Comment: @AzorAhai any efforts to increase the number of males in female-dominated areas of work or study would be applicable.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add that link to the question as an example? And I'd suggest clarifying that increasing students studying those fields count too, my first reading was that you were more specifically interested in hiring.

Comment: @AzorAhai done.

Answer (score 15):

Your question is a little confusing because on one hand (title) you ask about a movement, and on the other you ask about a government program.

I don't know about the latter, but [there is](https://nurse.org/articles/Male-Nurses-And-The-Profession/) an  "American Assembly for Men in Nursing".

As for starting some mere "encouragement" government program, if [Australia is a good proxy](https://www.smh.com.au/education/male-teachers-rare-breed-but-still-sought-after-20151030-gkmpp0.html), men migrated out of teaching in good part because the real pay for teachers fell. So one could argue that any mere PR program money could be better used to increase teachers' pay, which would naturally attract more men.

Even in US nursing, there are lot more men in the [higher paying](https://nurse.org/articles/Male-Nurses-And-The-Profession/) nursing jobs than in nursing in general:

> The nursing industry is still dominated by women, about 90 percent depending on the type of nursing. However, according to United States Bureau of Labor, the number of men who work as nurses has tripled since 1970, rising from 2.7 to 9.6 percent. [...]
>
> The average annual salary of a nurse anesthetist is $162,000, and data shows 41 percent of those working in that field are men"

Answer (score 3):

Your own source, (MenTeach) has a list of different programs for male teachers. So yes, there are programs. [Here is the link](http://menteach.org/resources/financial_resources_for_teaching), and here is a list of male-specific programs.

- [The Future Minority Male Teachers of California](https://www.csun.edu/eisner-education/future-minority-male-teachers-of-california)
- [Call Me Mister](https://www.clemson.edu/education/research/programs/callmemister/)
- [NYC Men Teach](https://www2.cuny.edu/academics/academic-programs/teacher-education-programs/nyc-men-teach/)

I can also think of others too like:

- [AAMIN](https://www.aamn.org/)

Comment: The first one only talk about minority men more specificly men of colour. It doesn't talk about men in general. Same goes with NYC men teach.

Comment: Also in second link I find nothing related to men.

Comment: @Fizz I agree that it's not what I was looking for, but this was the closest answer.

Comment: Minority Male is not all males. Males of Color is also not all males. I suppose the state believes increasing diversity means every one except white male.